# Grub 2.04 (Elementary OS 6)

Tags: elementary-project

I added a newer version of kernels but when running advanced options with start system it shows only 5.4.0, with which elementary was installed

(https://i.stack.imgur.com/fvdD3.png!)
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/qQTIP.jpg)

Update: Add boot list screenshot[image]

Update: amdgpu hardware error.
There are no problems in the official last version of Ubuntu.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Updated your grub with update-grub?

*edit*

So in /boot/grub/grub.cfg the kernels are stated in the menu list?

Also, when running update-grub, output shows kernel's like so:

```
Generating grub configuration file ...  
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-5.0.0-37-generic
```

Are the installed kernels shown?

The following should be sufficient:
`update-initramfs -c -k all`
`update-grub or grub-mkconfig -o /boot/grub/grub.cfg`

When no succes, you could try:
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair

Comment: Yes, but it didn't help

Comment: Then your grub conf is not updated or kernel is not installed. You did install kernel header, modules, images?
sudo dpkg -i *.deb

Comment: Yes, I did install header, modules and images, but it still does not display other kernel versions. Look screenshot, I added boot list

Comment: Concerning amdgpu messages: those are warnings, so no error. Should be ok.

So still no new kernel entries on boot?

Comment: You might try something like this:
https://www.phoronix.com/scan.php?page=news_item&px=Ubuntu-19.10-Radeon-RX-5700

Not sure if this is the cause of ur issue